# Upgrading old RCP project from Eclipse 3.2 to higher edition

Tags: eclipse, upgrade, rcp

I intent to upgrade my RCP project from Eclipse 3.2 to higher edition. But I can't find `CyclePartAction` class in `org.eclipse.ui.workbench_3.3.2xxx.jar` or higher edition. There is only `CycleBaseHandler` and its subclasses in the `org.eclipse.ui.internal` package. So the class using CyclePartAction can't be compiled. Has the class been removed? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Any class in package `org.eclipse.*.internal.` is internal implementation, they might be changed or removed in future release. `CyclePartAction` probably is moved to new package or removed, try to find the similar name class via `Ctrl+Shift+T`. If you can't find it in another package, you have to implement it in your code.

Comment: In this case it was removed, and was converted to commands/handlers.  `CycleBaseHandler` and its subclasses.